# bash aliases and awk escaping of quotes

Tags: bash, awk, alias, quote

I'm trying to create an alias for a command to see the memory use,

```
ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'
```

but, the naive,

```
#.bash_aliases
alias totalmem='ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}''
```

gives errors:

```
-bash: alias: END: not found
-bash: alias: {print: not found
-bash: alias: sum/1024}: not found
```

I've tried with double quotes,

`totalmem ="ps ... |awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'"`, or

`totalmem ='ps ... |awk "{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}"'`,
escaping,

`totalmem ='ps ... |awk \'{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}\''`,
or escaping double quotes ... but I can't seem to make it work.

`totalmem ='ps ... |awk \"{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}\"'`,

gives the error

```
awk: "{sum+=}
awk: ^ unterminated string
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/38249-define-alias-embeded-awk-command.html

Comment: Never need `grep` with `awk '$0!~/peruser/{sum+=$1}END{print sum/1024}'`

Comment: @Massagran, ...insofar as you're still around -- I'd like to encourage you to think about switching over to the answer suggesting a function, which avoids the problem altogether. (Functions are far more powerful than aliases -- they can perform conditional logic; they have their own call stack entry with an argument list; they can be exported to the environment; they work inside scripts by default, which aliases don't; etc). The [#bash IRC channel factoid on aliases](https://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias) has long said "if you have to ask, use a function instead". Those are wise words.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost have it, the `$` will be expanded in double-quotes, so that needs extra escaping:

```
alias totalmem='ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk "{sum+=\$1} END {print sum/1024}"'
```

Or with the pattern inside `awk` as suggested by *iiSeymour*:

```
alias totalmem='ps -u user -o rss,command | awk "!/peruser/ {sum+=\$1} END {print sum/1024}"'
```

Comment: thanks god of the hammer. I had just found a solution with `alias memuse='ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '"'"'{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'"'"''` but yours is cleaner

Comment: @Massagran  Thank you Massagran from me a macOS user. You just save my day.

Answer (score 20):

You can avoid quoting issues by using a shell function instead of an alias:

```
totalmem () {
  ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'
}
```

This is also more flexible, as you could allow `totalmem` to take arguments, such as a user name to pass to the `-u` option of `ps`, as in this example:

```
totalmem () {
  ps -u "$1" -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
alias totalmem='ps -u user -o rss,command | grep -v peruser | awk '\''{sum+=$1} END {print sum/1024}'\'
```

Explanation: you may use different kind of quotes for the same argument, like `"I'm double-quoted"'and I am $HOME-less'-and-i-am-not-quoted`. Hence if you need a single quote inside single quotes, you can add `'\''` which (1) terminates single quoting, (2) adds literal single quote with `\'`, (3) starts single quoting again.

(Aliases of this size are something that's better done as functions).