# Bash alias create current timestamp in filename

Tags: bash, git, date, adb

First off, I have read the post here: 
[Bash alias create file with current timestamp in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24236362/bash-alias-create-file-with-current-timestamp-in-filename)

However, when I run it, I keep getting the same timestamp. This makes no sense to me.

I am running Git bash (From git 2.16.2) on Windows 10. I have added the following line into my ~/.bash_aliases:
`alias logfile="adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/'$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)'-FullLogCat.log"`

This seems to create a log file and display the ADB logs on screen, as I want. However, the actual date seems to be "stuck" at the same time as the terminal is loaded. For example, I load the terminal at 2:29:09pm then wait until 2:30:00pm to call the alias, the file gets stamped as "2018-04-24@14h29m09s-FullLogCat.log". It seems like as the profile loads the aliases into memory, it executes the date function.

Is there a way to prevent this? Is this just a weird git bash thing?

Update: Solution

```
alias logfile='adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/ghannan/Desktop/adb-logs/''$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)''-FullLogCat.log
```

Answer (score 3):

This should really be a function (as the question you should ask yourself is "Is there any reason this *can't* be a function?"):

```
logfile () {
    dt=$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)
    output="/c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/$dt-FullLogCat.log"
    adb logcat -v threadTime *:V | tee "$output"
}
```

From the `bash` man page:

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `$` in the alias so that the date command runs each time you invoke the alias.  Currently it is only being run when you are creating the alias.

EDIT: You also need to remove the single quotes around the `date` expansion as others in this thread have pointed out.

```
$ alias logfile="adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/'$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)'-FullLogCat.log"
$ alias | grep adb
alias logfile='adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/'\''2018-04-24@13h39m08s'\''-FullLogCat.log'
```

You can see above, without escaping `$` the date is hardcoded into the alias.

```
$ alias logfile="adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/\$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)-FullLogCat.log"
$ alias | grep adb
alias logfile='adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/'\''$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)'\''-FullLogCat.log'
```

In this example, we have escaped the `$`, and it is now part of the alias and will run as expected

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but for some reason it didn't work. I looked up escaping the quotes (based on your suggestion) and got it working with:

alias logfile='adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/ghannan/Desktop/adb-logs/''$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)''-FullLogCat.log'

Further information found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash/42082956#42082956

Comment: The reason the version in this answer doesn't work is that it puts single-quotes around the command expansion (i.e. it has `...'$(date ...)'...`), and single-quotes prevent the command expansion from being run. The version that works has double-quotes around it instead, which allow command and variable expansions. BTW, I'd actually recommend avoiding all the quoting confusion by using a function instead of an alias -- see [chepner's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560796/bash-aliases-and-awk-escaping-of-quotes).

Comment: Or see my answer below :)

Comment: Yes, the single quotes need to be removed as well.. updated answer to reflect

Answer (score 1):

use single quotes to prevent the command substitution until the alias is actually executed.

```
alias logfile='adb logcat -v threadtime *:V | tee /c/Users/username/Desktop/adb-logs/$(date +%Y-%m-%d@%Hh%Mm%Ss)-FullLogCat.log'
# ............^................................................................................................................^
```